# How Can I Add multipe buttons on c# dynamically using point class?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Hello I try to add multiple Buttons on a panel on form and next to each other but instead it put them above each other.
I am using the following function.
the Code:

```
    private void CreatBtn()
    {
        Point[] p = new Point[6];
        string log = "";
       Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

        Button[] btn = new Button[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
                btn[i] = new Button();
                btn[i].Height = 65;
                btn[i].Width = 80;

                p[i] = new Point();
                p[i].X = i * 83;

                p[i].Y =0;

                log +=p.ToString() +"\n";
                btn[i].PointToClient(p[i]);
                btn[i].Show();         
        }

        panel1.Controls.AddRange(btn);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Left` value to your buttons

```
btn[i] = new Button();
btn[i].Height = 65;
btn[i].Width = 80;
btn[i].Left = i * 83; //Now they'll be next to each other.
```

You may also consider using the [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx).

Comment: I highly recommend the FlowLayoutPanel! D:

Answer (score 1):

Use flowLayoutPanel in the panel of it'll but the next to each other until the button reach the end of it, then it will make an new raw

```
 Point[] p = new Point[6];
        string log = "";


        Button[] btn = new Button[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            btn[i] = new Button();
            btn[i].Height = 65;
            btn[i].Width = 80;

            p[i] = new Point();
            p[i].X = i * 83;

            p[i].Y = 0;

            log += p.ToString() + "\n";
            btn[i].PointToClient(p[i]);
            btn[i].Show();
        }

        FlowLayoutPanel pan = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        pan.Width=500;//width of all buttons
        pan.Height = 100;
        pan.Controls.AddRange(btn);

        panel1.Controls.Add(pan);
```